# Should I convert scientific notation to float before RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I read a csv file. Some values are in scientific notation format. The dtype is int64, not float. I want to build random forest. Can RandomForestClassifier recognize scientific notation? Should I convert scientific notation to float before RandomForestClassifier? If I should, please tell me how, I'm new in python. Thank you very much.

[image]

Updated:

```
traindata = pd.read_csv("TrainingDay.csv")
sizes = traindata['Flow Bytes/s'].value_counts(sort = 1)
print(sizes)
```

Part of the Output:

```
5.648680e+04      1
5.443154e+04      1
3.378250e+04      1
2.347347e+03      1
5.682307e+04      1
2.361954e+03      1
1.270858e+04      1
8.157320e+03      1
9.558360e+02      1
1.272000e+09      1
Name: Flow Bytes/s, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Would you show some more code and data (in a code block, please don't use images)? `2.361954e+03` surely is not `int64`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have uploaded some code and part of the output. thank you.

Comment: `int64` refers to the `value_counts`, not the `traindata['Flow Bytes/s']` type.  You can see the type I think you are interested in with `traindata['Flow Bytes/s'].dtype`.

Comment: You can see all the column types with `traindata.dtypes`.  You may also be interested in `traindata.info()`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you very much. I use `sizes = traindata['Flow Bytes/s'].dtype`, the output is `float64`. Does it mean there is nothing to convert? I can use the data directly, right?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your variable name choice, but yes, I see no reason you can't use `traindata` as is.  Ofc, you'll need to use it properly with `sklearn`, but that's your battle ahead.  :-)

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you. `Flow Bytes/s` means the traffic on the network, `traindata` means this csv file is used for training random forest. I am cleansing the dataset. I didn't know whether I should do something on columns in scientific notation. Seems like I don't need to. Thank you. :-)

Comment: Note that it's situational. You should always verify the dtype. In this case the dtype was `float64`, but in other cases it might be dtype `object` (strings), in which case you should convert it with `traindata['Flow Bytes/s'] = traindata['Flow Bytes/s'].astype(float)`.

Comment: @tdy Very true!  Imported CSVs should always be checked.

Comment: @tdy Thank you for the heads up. I will check every column.